# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: users is not defined at eval in vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I am getting this error while populating the data into the table
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKx2J.png)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- {{console.log(users)}} -->
    <table class="table m-0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
          <!-- <td>{{ Country }}</td> -->
          <!-- <td>{{ user.id }}</td> -->
          <td>alksdmad</td>
          <td>
            <!-- <router-link :to="`/edit/${id}`"> -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm me-2">Edit</button>
            <!-- </router-link> -->
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import { useLoadUsers, deleteUser } from '@/firebase'
import { db } from "@/firebase";
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

// const users = ref([
//     {
//         id: doc.id
//     }
// ])

export default {
//   data() {
//     return {
//       users: ref([
        
//       ]),
//     };
//   },
  setup() {
    const users = ref([])
    onMounted( async () => {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
        let fbUsers = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          const user = {
            id: doc.id
          }
          fbUsers.push(user)
        });
        users.value = fbUsers
    })
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

I am using the using the code above to access the db data
alksdlkal da dlk as dlasjdhaskjdaksj dkjashdk jashkjdas ksjd ja hdkaj kjdahs kjd asksj dh akjsh dkjas hdkjah dkjash dkjhaskjd askjhdakj askj hkajsdhkjashd kjashdkjhd kjaskj dakjd askjd

Comment: Please share the code as text

Comment: Please repost the original code as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define the `users` property directly inside the `setup` hook :

```js
export default{
 setup() {
    const users = ref([])
    onMounted( async () => {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
        let fbUsers = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          const user = {
            id: doc.id
          }
          fbUsers.push(user)
        });
        users.value = fbUsers
    })
  return {users}
  },
}
```

Comment: not working. Its saying[Vue warn]: Property "users" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <UserList> 
  at <Home onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>

Comment: You should add `return {users}` at the end of setup hook

Comment: Sure, i did it.